# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `index.js`:

Tags: react-native, babeljs, yarnpkg, genymotion

in my folder project when I run react-native run-android I get an error in yarn start terminal

```
   bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`
 from `index.js`: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

I restart my system and now I have not no errors

Answer (score 0):

try to reset your metro server

```
npm run start --reset-cache
```